# Retrieving two columns from a table using stored procedure in Snowflake

Tags: javascript, sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm trying to retrieve the data from the table using the function and store them in an array. But when I tried to return one of the two arrays, I didn't get any data. Don't understand where I'm going wrong.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_DATE()
        RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
        LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
        AS
        $$
            var array1 = [];
            var array2 = [];
            array1,array2 = get_columns_data(); // want to get those two array values from the function for further use
            return array1; //This is not printing or returning anything

            function get_columns_data()
            {
                var arr1 = [];
                var arr2 = [];
                
                cmdl = {sqlText: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL, COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) AS UNIQUE FROM TABLE1;`} //query to get two column values
                stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmdl);
                
                var a = stmt.execute();
                while(a.next())
                {
                    var one = a.getColumnValue('TOTAL');
                    arr1.push(one);
                    var two = a.getColumnValue('UNIQUE');
                    arr2.push(two);
                }
                return arr1,arr2;  //returning two arrays; Don't know if this is the correct method to return two arryas
            }
        $$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line won't work on JavaScript:

```
return arr1,arr2;
```

Instead, you can return an array of arrays:

```
return [arr1,arr2];
```

Then you can receive the array of arrays in a single var:

```
arrays = get_columns_data();
```

Testing how returning with a comma won't work, and then fixing with by returning an array:

[image]