# What is the best way to set multiple variables in snowflake from a table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Equivalent declaration and setting the variable as below.

```
DECLARE @name varchar(255)
       ,@address varchar(255)
       ,@country varchar(255)

SELECT @name = name
      ,@address = address
      ,@country = country
    FROM tbl_address
    WHERE id =5
```

When converting this code into snowflake SP, what's the best way to handle the declaration and setting the variable from table.

[image]

Comment: This answer has an example of a stored procedure with two variables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64492937/retrieving-two-columns-from-a-table-using-stored-procedure-in-snowflake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to assgin multiple variables at once:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tbl_address AS
SELECT 5 AS id, 'a' AS name, 'b' AS address, 'c' AS country;

SET (name, address, country) = (SELECT name, address, country 
                                FROM tbl_address WHERE id = 5);

SELECT $name, $address, $country;
-- a, b, c
```

The requirement is that the suqbquery used to fetch values cannot return more than 1 row.